# For loop for reading several json from url

Tags: python, json, for-loop, pandas

I have to create several a dataset containing several json files taken from urls.

I managed to import one in the format I need:

```
url = "https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
data = data.transpose()
data.columns = data.iloc[0]
data = data.drop(data.index[[0]])
```

since I have a long list of urls what I need is a for-loop that repeats this bit of code for all of them. My attempt has been:

```
for i in urls:
data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
data = json.loads(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
data = test.transpose()
data.columns = data.iloc[0]
data = data.drop(data.index[[0]])
df.append(data)
```

where urls is a list of string containing the address i.e.

```
"https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku=125T:FT0111"
```

and df is an empty dataframe with the same columns as those in the dataframe generated by each url in the for-loop

when I run it I keep getting the following error:

```
 raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

 ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

error that does not appear when I ran the first piece of code for a single url.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

a new attempt was to change the for-loop as follows:

```
for i in urls:
     data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
     try:
         data = json.loads(data)
     except:
         print(data) 
         print(i)
         exit(-1)
     data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
     data = data.transpose()
     data.columns = data.iloc[0]
     data = data.drop(data.index[[0]])
     df.append(data)
```

Now I get the error:

```
   data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `data = json.loads(data)` line seems to have gone AWOL...

Comment: you are absolutely right. I added but I keep getting an error. I'll edit the question

Comment: Your new error indicates that one of the URLs does not return a valid JSON. I assume you didn't try them all one by one in your first snippet. Surround `json.loads` with `try/except` and print the offending `i` and/or `data` to verify what you are getting.

Comment: I'm relatively new to python, would you be so kind to show me to correct syntax for that? many thanks

Comment: Python is hard to write in comments due to indent syntax, but... replacing `<CR>` with newlines and `#` with spaces... `try:<CR>####data = json.loads(data)<CR>except:<CR>####print(data)<CR>####print(i)<CR>#### exit(-1)<CR>...`

Comment: I tried and now I get the error: data = pd.DataFrame(data.items()) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: With the code I just put in the previous comments, you should not be getting an error at all. #cowboydebugging It should just print what the offending URL was. (And be sure to remove the extra lines when you're done debugging)

Comment: I edited the question so you can see if I wrote correctly.

Comment: In that case, JSON is correct but not having `items`. Move the `data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())` inside `try:`.

Comment: now I get data = data.transpose()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transpose' I have also tried to move it inside and move all the lines beginning with data but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could just use the pandas native [read_json function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd


url_base = "https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?product_sku={}"
products = ["125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111", "125T:FT0111"]

raw_data_list = []

for sku in products:
    url = url_base.format(sku)
    try:
        raw_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        if raw_data != "":
            raw_data_list.append(raw_data)
    except:
        pass

data = "[" + (",".join(raw_data_list)) + "]"
data = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
data
```

Comment: Thanks but I got this error:  loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None) ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: @johnred The code in my answer runs fine for me. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I run python 2.7 on Spyder. I think that it works for you because the list of urls that I have has some links that are empty. Those links raise an error when I try to import them. Would it be possible to create a list of only "good" links, in the sense filtering out all those links that fail data = json.loads(data) ? thanks.

Comment: @johnred Since I cannot really see your result, it's hard for me to fix my code, but I changed it to catch exceptions when reading the url

Comment: it does not run into an error and returns data. However, the result for one url gives me  dataframe with 48 columns and I should append each new data row to this dataframe. Yours returns me a dataframe with 383 rows x 345 columns

Comment: Could you give me the product ids and I can have a look at the problem?

Comment: how can I send you a file?

Comment: Just post a few example SKUs that fail

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're missing the json.loads() line within your for loop

```
url = "https://cws01.worldstores.co.uk/api/product.php?    
product_sku=125T:FT0111"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
data = data.transpose()
data.columns = data.iloc[0]
data = data.drop(data.index[[0]])


for i in urls:
    data = urllib2.urlopen(str(i)).read()
    data = json.loads(data) # <- ADDED
    data = pd.DataFrame(data.items())
    data = test.transpose()
    data.columns = data.iloc[0]
    data = data.drop(data.index[[0]])
    df.append(data)
```

Comment: I added and I edited the question but I still get an error